# Most efficient way to group and sort by property with sections without lodash

Tags: javascript

Using vanilla JavaScript and without lodash, what is the most efficient way to group an array of objects by value in the following manner?

For example if the input data is:

`const data = [{year: "2021", name: "Rick"}, {year: "2020", name: "Joe"}, {year: "2021", name: "Sam"}, {year: "2019", name: "Sally"}, {year: "2019", name: "Jess"}];`

and the output data is:

`const result = [{year: "2021", data: [{year: "2021", name: "Rick"}, {year: "2021", name: "Sam"}]}, {year: "2020", data: [{year: "2020", name: "Joe"}]}, {year: "2019", data: [{year: "2019", name: "Sally"}, {year: "2019", name: "Jess"}]}]`

Answer (score -2):

You can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

In the reducer function, check whether the new array contains an item with the same `year` property. If so, push the current item to that item's `data` property. Otherwise, construct the appropriate object and push it to the array.

```js
const data = [{year: "2021", name: "Rick"}, {year: "2020", name: "Joe"}, {year: "2021", name: "Sam"}, {year: "2019", name: "Sally"}, {year: "2019", name: "Jess"}];

const result = data.reduce((a, b) => {
    const year = a.find(e => e.year == b.year);
    if (year) {
        year.data.push(b);
    } else {
        a.push({year: b.year, data: [b]})
    }
    return a;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```